# Angular using HashLocationStrategy but hide # in url

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new on Angular developing a frontend for my website.
For now, I just starting build it on my http://localhost:4200 and I got stuck on using HashLocationStrategy.

The routing was successful route without loading entire page using

```
this.router.navigate();
```

and also successful to route back without loading entire page to when click back button using

```
this.location.back();
```

The problem come when I directly go to some page (ex: http://localhost:4200/detail/1). When I click back button on the page that I enter it directly to that url, it will refreshed entire page and will back to previous page.

I read some article on the internet that suggest me to use HashLocationStrategy.
I tried and it works, but the url of my page will added # for every page.

What I want to do is removing the # on my url, but still keep the HashLocationStrategy that let me click back button without refreshing entire page when I directly go to some url page.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks

Comment: You can not do that , Hash location strategy will always use hash for routing if you don't want hash in your route use path location strategy

Comment: It's worth attempting to fix your initial problem rather than trying to hack HashLocationStrategy. It's bad practice to "break the back button" - you should always respect navigation via the back button

Comment: @Aarsh I tried using the PathLocationStrategy, but it makes my back button will refreshed entire page when i directly go to some url page on my website

Comment: @KurtHamilton I'm sorry, but I saw this website https://m.lativ.com.tw/
I don't know what method they use, but if you try to go to some detail page https://m.lativ.com.tw/detail/46714041 and click the back button, it will shown # on the page that redirected after click the back button, and its not refreshing entire page for it. I tried to find what method they use, but I found HashLocationStrategy that similar for it, but seems it's not what I need to find.

Let me try to research more, thanks

Comment: Are you sure that it's not a "fragment"? https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments